# Firebase Admin Java SDK - Database Sync Data Retrieve

Tags: java, spring, firebase, asynchronous, firebase-admin

**I am using:**

- Java (Client/Server)
- Firebase Admin SDK (Server)
- Spring Framework (Server)

**Problem:**

I am trying to develop the server, based on Spring Framework that would work together with Firebase's services.

I have encountered a problem with the database. There is no problem to send a request from the client to the server that would update data points. However, there is one when I want to retrieve it.

Firebase's SDK handles this task with async methods, but I need to be able to return the object via Spring Framework.

Async code that retrieves needed data from DB:

```
DatabaseReference ref = db.getReference("users").child(uid);
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        UserData data = dataSnapshot.getValue(UserData.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }

});
```

Spring Framework server-side controller that needs to respond (return) to the client with the object:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/retrieve", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public UserData retrieve_user_data(@RequestBody String uid) {

        // TODO: I need to retrieve the object from async method and return it here.
        return userData;

    }
```

What options do I have that would solve my issue? I would appreciate any advice!

Comment: Use a `CountDownLatch` or a similar synchronization primitive to bridge the two APIs. For instance you can decrement a latch in the `onDataChange()` event handler, and wait for the latch to become zero in your Spring data mapping code.

Comment: You should also use the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` method.

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka seems to work! Thanks a lot!